# Android Jetpack Compose Navigation doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making an android app using Jetpack Compose and I have a problem. I used navigation to change the screen. I wanted to change firstRunLayout to loginLayout. You can see that i put that log.d code in order to check if this worked and I found out that logcat prints that successfully. I want to change the screen when I navigate. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
@Composable
fun setUpNavHost(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.FirstRun.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.FirstRun.route) {
            firstRunLayout(navController)
            Log.d("NavHost", "FirstRun")
        }
        composable(route = Screen.Login.route) {
            loginLayout()
            Log.d("NavHost", "Login")
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. I checked that there are Composable annotations at those layouts.

```
Button(onClick = {
                    Log.d("FirstRunActivity", "Button clicked")
                    navController.navigate(route = Screen.Login.route)
                }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEF4746)), modifier = Modifier
                    .height(40.dp)
                    .width(300.dp), shape = RoundedCornerShape(50)) {
                    Text(text = "Continue", fontSize = 15.sp, color = Color.White)
                }
```

I used the button to navigate. You can see navController.navigate above. Also, this is the way that this navController was declared.

```
class FirstRunActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MemorizableTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Color(0xFFEF4746)
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    setUpNavHost(navController = navController)
                    
                    firstRunLayout(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the declaration of navController, and how you navigate from firstRunLayout to loginLayout, what's the code used for the navigation, there is nothing wrong with your navHost.

Comment: @Kaido I added it and you can see the code ↑

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `Activity`, you call the `navHost`, then you call the `firstRunLayout` screen, so the `firstRunLayout` screen will be on the top of the `navHost`, you need to delete the call of `firstRunLayout` in your activity, so your code should look like this:

```
class FirstRunActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MemorizableTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Color(0xFFEF4746)
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    setUpNavHost(navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```